# Getting Axios response data from a response with an array

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

This is the response from my server

```
{"message":"Resource Created","payload": 
[{"id":"5d80270413452b6732fd5217","name":"asdf"}]}
```

I am trying to set the `id` to my state.

Currently trying this.

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:8081/companies`, company)
     .then(request => request.data.payload.id)
     .then(id => {
         commit('setCreatedCompanyID', id)
     })
```

I believe the error is with this line

```
.then(request => request.data.payload.id)
```

How can I get the first ID from the response array?

Comment: `.then(request => request.data.payload[0].id)`

Comment: That works. thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `myArray[index]` to access the `index`-th element of the `myArray` array. Such as:

```
.then(request => request.data.payload[0].id)
```

Demo:

```js
axios.get(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/rin05`)
  .then(request => request.data.payload[0].id)
  .then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
Check the console
```